# Saving the data from SparkStreaming Workers to Database

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, datastax, datastax-enterprise

In SparkStreaming should we off load the saving part to another layer because SparkStreaming context is not available when we use [SparkCassandraConnector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) if our database is cassandra. Moreover, even if we use some other database to save our data then we need to create connection on the worker every time we process a batch of rdds. Reason being connection objects are not serialized.

1. Is it recommended to create/close connections at workers?
2. It would make our system tightly coupled with the existing database tomorrow we may change the database

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, it is absolutely fine to create/close connections at workers.
   But, make sure you don't do it for each and every record. It is
   recommended to do it at the partition level or at a level where
   connections are created/closed for a group of records.
2. You can decouple it by passing a variable and deciding on the type of DB connection at runtime.

Possible duplicate of:
[Handle database connection inside spark streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709769/handle-database-connection-inside-spark-streaming)

Read this link, it should clarify some of you questions
[Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)

Hope this help!